# How to change user to submit different user same machine

Tags: git, github, version-control

How to change diffrent 
I use with my friend an pair programming and we want to quickly switch 
between two repo to submit with different user each sometimes mine sometimes her

This is my friend repo

https://github.com/SofiaTa/mzr

and when she initialize the repo she get the following

`echo "# mzr" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin git@github.com:SofiaTa/mzr.git
git push -u origin master`

Now from my mac I did the following

```
git config --global user.email "shopia.tatriak@gmail.com"

git config --global user.name “SofiaTa”
```

now we want to submit the repo and we got error

we did

`git add .
git commit -m “first commit”
git remote add origin git@github.com:SofiaTa/mzr.git
git push -u origin master`

**ERROR:** P

> ermission to SofiaTa/mzr.git denied to Jenny. fatal: Could not read
>   from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

But I’ve change the config .

I know that she can add a collaborator but I don’t want , I want her to submit from my mac her work

There is another config which I should modify to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to commit something from your friends computer with your GitHub account while she is the only one with write access to the repository.

This is not possible, as the requests and pushes made to GitHub are in fact user dependent and authorize only by users and not by computers. That means: **You need write access to push to the repository!** The rights need to apply to the user you are using.

Solution 1: If she is your co-worker on a project, I don't see why she shouldn't **give you access to the repository**. You can look the permission settings up in [the GitHub documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/access-permissions-on-github/). If she doesn't want you to have too many rights you can set them accordingly.

Optional: You could furthermore build up a organisation within GitHub if there are more workers likely to join.

Solution 2: **Don´t switch accounts.** If it is important (...) that you use her computer then keep signed in and use her account. You can comment your name (commit message) if you want to keep track, who made what. This is an uncommon and not recommended approach but it may help you.